# detect all windows minimized from c# application

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize

how to detect all windows(of other applications) minimized from c# application

Comment: i have to monitor all opened application minimize activity from my application

Comment: Is it a Windows Forms application? WPF? etc.

Comment: it is a windows forms application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use example from here http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDesktopWindows then just check window state

Comment: This answer was very useful, thanks. But I'll just point out that linking to examples on PInvoke.net can be problematic - that particular example has edited five times since this answer was posted here at SO, and it looks very different now than it did then. Furtunately, you can see the old versions on PInvoke.net. Anyway, the current version seems to work fine, so thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor what's going on in the system, then you want to set up a [CBT Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28VS.85%29.aspx). That will keep you notified when windows are created, destroyed, minimized, maximized, moved, activated, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetWindowState() WinAPI function

Answer (score -1):

For Windows Forms you can look at the property [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) on the Form object. Minimized windows will have a state of `FormWindowState.Minimized`.

Comment: i have to monitor other application activity not my application

Comment: @Suriyan: So, elaborate it in your question. Be more clear if you want a prompt answer.